# \tableofcontents inside breakable tcolorbox

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

I want to put the toc (with \tableofcontents) of a larger document (with a lot of \includes, so I do not know how to make a simple example out of it) into a breakable tcolorbox. The toc is correct, the box appears but I get always at fist two pages with an empty broken box (containing only 1 empty line) and the toc starts at the 3rd page, where the title now sticks
near the top of the box. The "lines before break" option has no affect at all.
Is there anybody who knows, how to avoid the empty pages?
Thanks in advance,

Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

Soon after my question I found out the solution myself. I took the code from the tcolorbox doc. In the first part "tcolorbox.doc.abstract.tex" I found the solution in the last block.
Best regards.

Comment: To better help future readers who might have similar needs as you, perhaps you can provide an example demonstrating what you found.

Comment: You can answer your question to help others that have had (or that have) your same problem. Thank you very much.